# Is there any practical use for a piecewise written in only one function?

Tags: functions

I spent around an hour and figured out how to form a piecewise from one function, and it's annoyingly complicated to write out or calculate, and would be much easier to just write the piecewise.

The function is as follows:

f(x)= g(x) + ((h(x)^i(x))-(g(x)^i(x))

where g(x) is the left side function, h(x) is the right side function, and i(x) is a binary logic gate determining when to switch from g(x) to h(x)

i(x)= (ceil(x) summation n=(a+1) (1))^(0^(ceil(x) summation n=(a+1) (1)))

g(x) , x >= a

Here's the graph on desmos since I don't know how to format: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wgd5v2cpft

As you can see, its bulky and annoying to work with, but it takes a piecewise and makes it one function. I don't think there'd be any practical use for this, but there might be, and it'd be cool to know. I do admit this post is to brag about what I did because I am quite proud I figured this out, but feel free to criticize me.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: a) you can write plainly $f(x)=ceil(x)-a$. b) I is rather unusual to see $0^{f(x)}$. c) Do you know Heaviside function ? It would be very natural to introduce it here. d) Your juvenile enthousiasm is sympathetic ; this kind of things could find maybe its place [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) but honestly Math Stack Exchange is not the best place for such a question.

Answer (score 1):

Well, "never" is a long time, but as far as my experience goes I can agree with the futility: that's why the notation $$f(x)=\begin{cases}u_1(x)&\text{if condition1}\\ u_2(x)&\text{if condition2}\\\vdots\\ u_n(x)&\text{if condition_n}\end{cases}$$ exists.

In programming this is even formalized by a plethora of instructions, like the **switch** command of c++ and the ternary operator a?b:c, still in c++.